# Unable to downcast array members to protocol type

Tags: swift

I have two protocols `Valid` and `Resetable` and an array of `inputViews` that is of type `[Valid]`. That all works fine. So now I've got my `Resetable` protocol:

```
protocol Resetable: class {
    func reset()
}
```

Now, everything inside of `inputViews` also conforms to the `Resetable` protocol, so what I want to do is basically loop through and call `reset()` on each member. If I do this then it will work:

```
    for input in inputViews {
        (input as! Resetable).reset()
    }
```

But i've extended `Array` with the following:

```
extension Array where Element:Resetable {
    func resetAll() {
        forEach({ $0.reset() })
    }
}
```

So what I really want to be able to do is downcast `inputViews` entirely and call `resetAll()`.

I tried:

```
    let resetableViews = inputViews.map({ $0 as! Resetable })
    resetableViews.resetAll()
```

But it says `Using Resetable as a concrete type conforming to Resetable is not supported`

How can I achieve this by using `resetAll()`?

Comment: Resettable is actually spelled with two t's, like forgettable/regrettable, but unlike deletable/depletable, or marketable/pocketable.

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood the question / specs.  Freely taking from Rob Napier, how about:

```
protocol Resettable {
    func reset() -> Resettable
}

struct ResettableArray {
    var array: [Resettable]
    init(_ array:[Resettable]) { self.array = array }
    func resetAll() -> [Resettable] {
        return array.map( { $0.reset() } )
    }
}

class dummy: Resettable {
    func reset() -> Resettable {
        print("Reset one element")
        return self
    }
}

let resettableDummy = ResettableArray([dummy(), dummy()])
resettableDummy.resetAll()
```